# How to write test class for this?

Tags: apex, controller, code-coverage

```
public with sharing class ToggleController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

    public static List< Contact > fetchContact (Id accId, String status) {

        return [SELECT Status_c, FirstName, LastName, Email
                FROM Contact WHERE Status_c=: status AND AccountId=:accid ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below steps -

1. Prepare data in @testSetup - create account and contact with status__c and accountId of inserted account.
2. Create a @isTest method and query the account. Call the fetchContact method and pass the accountId and contact's status as mentioned in the @testSetup method.

You can follow below best practices of test class-
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_data